# How to use this "selectionsort" function

Tags: c++

I have to sort this vector of objects of the "Aluno" class alphabetically. I got this global function that does it, given to us by our professor:

```
void selectionsort(Aluno *A,int size){
    int i=0,j=0,aux=0;
    for(i=0;i<size -1;i++){
        aux=i;
        for(j=i+1;i<size;j++){
            if((A+j)->getnome() < (A+aux)->getnome())  //getnome() = getname() in english;
                aux=j;
            troca(A+aux,A+i);
        }
    }
}
```

but every time I call it in `main()`, it breaks. Some allocation error. Could you guys help me? Am I calling it wrong?
I called it like this: `selectionsort(A,4);`

Comment: How are you defining `A` in `main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the condition on your inner (j) for loop:  You're checking against the wrong variable.